# Change empty cells in gtsummary::tbl_merge

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have merged two tables with different rows, resulting in empty cells. I would like to replace the empty cell with an explicit "Missing" or "---" (this may also be something to implement within `tbl_merge` for a future feature). I tried playing around with the superstar function `modify_table_styling` but am having trouble finding the rows. I've tried `everything()` and `is.na(estimate)`. Also, note that I actually have a tbl_merge on a tbl_merge, so my `my_df$table_body` is even more complex to find row identifiers in.

Thank you for your help!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

tbl_dense <-
  trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)

tbl_sparse <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, response) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)

tbl_merge(list(tbl_dense, tbl_sparse)) %>% 
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) |  |  |
| Unknown | 7 | 4 |  |  |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.84 (0.24, 1.57) | 0.52 (0.19, 1.20) |  |  |
| Unknown | 6 | 4 |  |  |
| T Stage |  |  |  |  |
| T1 | 28 (29%) | 25 (25%) |  |  |
| T2 | 25 (26%) | 29 (28%) |  |  |
| T3 | 22 (22%) | 21 (21%) |  |  |
| T4 | 23 (23%) | 27 (26%) |  |  |
| Grade |  |  |  |  |
| I | 35 (36%) | 33 (32%) |  |  |
| II | 32 (33%) | 36 (35%) |  |  |
| III | 31 (32%) | 33 (32%) |  |  |
| Tumor Response | 28 (29%) | 33 (34%) | 28 (29%) | 33 (34%) |
| Unknown | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| Patient Died | 52 (53%) | 60 (59%) |  |  |
| Months to Death/Censor | 23.5 (17.4, 24.0) | 21.2 (14.6, 24.0) |  |  |

```r
  
# Likely with this do-it-all function
# modify_table_styling(
#   column = estimate,
#   rows = is.na(estimate), # Not sure how to select rows
#   missing_symbol = "MISSING"
# )
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the `modify_table_styling()` function is the way to go. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")

tbl_dense <-
  trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)

tbl_sparse <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, response) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)

tbl <-
  tbl_merge(list(tbl_dense, tbl_sparse)) %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = everything(),
    rows = !is.na(variable),
    missing_symbol = "MISSING"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works on the reprex but I'm getting `Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit` on my actual (huge) regression table. Unfortunately I think this problem is beyond the scope of `gtsummary` as well as my basic computer knowledge :/ Running R 4.1.0, RStudio 1.4.1717, gtsummary 1.4.2.900, macOS 11.4

Comment: gtsummary tables can get large, particularly large data regression models. You can perhaps build your tables sequentially. When each table is done, this function can be used to reduce the size. http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/bstfun/reference/gtsummary_butcher.html

Comment: Thanks for introducing that function! I tried reducing each individual table and then also the combined table, and while it reduced from a huge 200.1 Mb to 20.6 Mb, I still get `Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit`. Empty cells will do for this or I'll change outside of gtsummary.